# Adding users directly from the database [UserFrosting 0.3.1]

Tags: userfrosting

I want to add a number of test user accounts and it's a lot faster to do it directly from the Database.

There are a couple of fields that I cannot figure out:

1. **secret_token:** How do I generate this on the fly? Is it necessary? Can I copy it from other accounts?
2. **password:** Even though I have created some accounts the normal way (register page), with the same password, the password fields are different for each user. Therefore I assume it's not a simple copy/paste case (question also applies to changing a user's password from the DB).

Any insight appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`secret_token` is an md5 hash, and is created by the [`User::generateActivationToken()`](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/userfrosting/models/database/User.php#L563-L568) method.  It is used for special account activities like email verification, password reset, and password creation for new accounts.

`password` is a 60-character *salted* hash generated by [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) using the [bcrypt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).  Since the salt is randomly generated each time a password is created, it will be different from user to user, even if their plaintext passwords are exactly the same.  Indeed, [this is the purpose of using a salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

If you are just setting up test accounts for development purposes, you can leave `secret_token` empty and use `password_hash` to generate passwords (perhaps by running a custom PHP script from the command line).

If you need to generate accounts in bulk for real users, you may want to set a `secret_token` but leave the *password* empty, generate a "password reset" event for each user, and then send them a password creation email so they can choose their own passwords.  This is in fact what is done in the [`createUser`](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/userfrosting/controllers/UserController.php#L405-L522) controller method:

```
$data['password'] = "";

...

$user = new User($data);

...

$user->newEventPasswordReset();
```

You can see the code for `newEventPasswordReset` [here](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/userfrosting/models/database/User.php#L400-L409).